# Variance of an MA(q) model in R?

Tags: r, variance, moving-average, moving-average-model

How exactly can I calculate the variance of an MA(q) model in R?

Comment: Could you be more specific what you mean by the variance of a model. The distribution of the population, or the distribution of estimates of parameters, or the distribution of a prediction?